# Converting stand wp_list_pages() to custom style

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Im not sure how to change wp_list_pages() output from this

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children current_page_item">
<a href="http://website.com/about">About</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://website.com/team">Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

to this

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://website.com/about" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">About</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="http://website.com/team">Team</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

In the past I hacked into the wordpress core files to change the layout but it would break after I updated wordpress.  So now I want to stylise  wp_list_pages() so that i dont have to hack wordpress internally, perhaps something i can add inside the function.php file within my theme?

I looked at the walker extend but it seems very confusing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the filter 'wp_list_pages'?

Comment: [Try this custom walker class.](https://pastebin.com/prpDr86T)

Comment: @dev please check my answer.

Comment: @dev please check my ans alos. <li id="menu-item-2617" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-2617"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2618" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2618"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/team/">Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

Comment: @dev please check my updated code.

Comment: SallyCJ thank you, it seems to work but i need remove <li class="pagenav">Pages<ul> so it appears inline and also to show 'active' class as the selected menu item similar to this <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" ?

Comment: SallyCj thanks again im sorry i forgot to add 'title_li'  => '' to wp_list_pages. Now trying to work out 'active' menu item bit.

Comment: @dev you should at least upvote for developer encouragement.

Comment: SallyCJ thanks Ive solved it

Comment: You're welcome! And btw, **do not** hack into the WordPress core files again, unless you're absolutely 101% sure that there are no other options available for you in your specific case. All the best! =)

Comment: @Dev if my answer is correct, then you should accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please check updated code:

1) Add below code in function.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'custom-ppl' ),
    ) );
 and from admin menu settings select primary as per the screen and save.
```

[image]

2) Code for display menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,    
    'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu_add
));
```

3) Code for function.php

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_add extends Walker {
    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'dropdown-menu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        if($depth=='0'){
         $classes[] = 'dropdown menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        } else if($depth=='1'){ 
         $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;   
        }

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;

        if($depth=='0'){
        $item_output .= '<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        }
        else if($depth=='1'){
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        }    


        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 1, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }

} // Walker_Nav_Menu
```

Hope this work.

Comment: Thank you, however the output im seeing is -- 
<li id="menu-item-17" class="dropdown menu-item-17">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-2" class="dropdown menu-item-2">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-11" class="dropdown menu-item-11">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></a>
</li> -- its missing the link and link text and child items

Comment: Thank you but I don't use 'Menus'. A user simply adds a new page and it appears within navigation - simple. I if i now tested your code would it work? including dropdown sub menu?